# Using elementary operations, find a condition on $\lambda$ so that the system is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

The linear system is:

$$\begin{aligned} 3x +2y + z &= 0\\ 6x + 4y + \lambda z &= 0\end{aligned}$$

I have had a few attempts at this with little success. I have also seen similar questions asked here but I can not wrap my head around them.
I understand a consistent system requires at least 1 solution set. So I have been trying to equate λ to the remnants of a reduced system but i have had no luck.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You could append a summary of your attempts. I have formatted your question properly, so you don't need to figure that out anymore.

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and adding to the second one we get
$$-2z+\lambda z=0$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am tired and for some reason was going along this path but then decided for what ever reason to multiply -2 to the  λ instead of adding it. I should rest and later write out my operation changes to avoid that mistake. Thank you again.